# Parallelism in Java. Divide and Conquer, Quick Sort

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Parallelizing quick sort via multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425126/java-parallelizing-quick-sort-via-multi-threading)

I am really sorry that i created bad question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957609/how-to-sort-array-in-threads-by-any-algorithm), 
so i don't want repeat my mistakes.
I find [article](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/02/26/parallelism-in-net-part-11-divide-and-conquer-via-parallel-invoke/) there says how to implement parallelism in divide and conquer algorithm.
Multithreading is implemented using the Parallel.Invoke Method.
So question is how to implement this syntax in Java and optimize threads works with CPUs

```
Parallel.Invoke(
        () => QuickSortInternal(array, left, last - 1),
        () => QuickSortInternal(array, last + 1, right)
    );
```

here i have sample in c#

```
public static void QuickSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    QuickSortInternal(array, 0, array.Length - 1);
}

private static void QuickSortInternal<T>(T[] array, int left, int right)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (left >= right)
    {
        return;
    }

    SwapElements(array, left, (left + right) / 2);
    int last = left;
    for (int current = left + 1; current <= right; ++current)
    {
        if (array[current].CompareTo(array[left]) < 0)
        {
            ++last;
            SwapElements(array, last, current);
        }
    }

    SwapElements(array, left, last);

    Parallel.Invoke(
    () => QuickSortInternal(array, left, last - 1),
    () => QuickSortInternal(array, last + 1, right)
);
}

static void SwapElements<T>(T[] array, int i, int j)
{
    T temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

and in Java

```
    static void quickSort(int numbers[], int array_size)
{
  q_sort(numbers, 0, array_size - 1);
}


static void q_sort(int numbers[], int left, int right)
{
  int pivot, l_hold, r_hold;

  l_hold = left; // левая точка left point
  r_hold = right; // правая точка right point
  pivot = numbers[left]; //средняя самая левая 
  while (left < right) // пока левая меньше правой
  {
    while ((numbers[right] >= pivot) && (left < right)) // пока правый элемент больше среднего и левый меньше правого
      right--; // правый уменьшаем
    if (left != right) // пока левый не равен правому
    {
      numbers[left] = numbers[right];// правый присвамваем левому
      left++;// левый наращиваем
    }
    while ((numbers[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))// 
      left++;
    if (left != right)
    {
      numbers[right] = numbers[left];
      right--;
    }
  }
  numbers[left] = pivot;
  pivot = left;
  left = l_hold;
  right = r_hold;
  if (left < pivot)
    q_sort(numbers, left, pivot-1);
  if (right > pivot)
    q_sort(numbers, pivot+1, right);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int m[]={4,6,2,6,34,6,32,43,2,6,76};
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(m[i] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        quickSort(m,m.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(m[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: If the question linked by @Ronald solved your problem, we should close this as a duplicate.