# Multithreaded Merge Sort

Tags: java, mergesort

Can someone please give me a link or provide me with java code of a multithreaded merge sort?

Preferable one that uses an executor!

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about you give us your single-threaded mergesort code and we might be able to help you parallelise it.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210185/correctly-multithreaded-quicksort-or-mergesort-algo-in-java

Answer (score 7):

Here is my version of MergeSort using 2 threads, it can be extended to n threads easily (just split the original array into n sub-arrays). For 10 million numbers, it is faster than its single-thread counterpart by about 25%.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MergeSortThreaded {

    public static void finalMerge(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];
        int i=0; 
        int j=0; 
        int r=0;
        while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
            if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
                result[r]=a[i];
                i++;
                r++;
            } else {
                result[r]=b[j];
                j++;
                r++;
            }
            if (i==a.length) {
                while (j<b.length) {
                    result[r]=b[j];
                    r++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (j==b.length) {
                while (i<a.length) {
                    result[r]=a[i];
                    r++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] original = new int[10000000];
        for (int i=0; i<original.length; i++) {
            original[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[] subArr1 = new int[original.length/2];
        int[] subArr2 = new int[original.length - original.length/2];
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, subArr1, 0, original.length/2);
        System.arraycopy(original, original.length/2, subArr2, 0, original.length - original.length/2);

        Worker runner1 = new Worker(subArr1);
        Worker runner2 = new Worker(subArr2);
        runner1.start();
        runner2.start();
        runner1.join();
        runner2.join();
        finalMerge (runner1.getInternal(), runner2.getInternal());
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("2-thread MergeSort takes: " + (float)elapsedTime/1000 + " seconds");
    }

}

class Worker extends Thread {
    private int[] internal;

    public int[] getInternal() {
        return internal;
    }

    public void mergeSort(int[] array) {
        if (array.length > 1) {
            int[] left = leftHalf(array);
            int[] right = rightHalf(array);

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);

            merge(array, left, right);
        }
    }

    public int[] leftHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int[] left = new int[size1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
        return left;
    }

    public int[] rightHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int size2 = array.length - size1;
        int[] right = new int[size2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            right[i] = array[i + size1];
        }
        return right;
    }

    public void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right) {
        int i1 = 0;   
        int i2 = 0;   

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length && left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
                result[i] = left[i1];   
                i1++;
            } else {
                result[i] = right[i2];   
                i2++;
            }
        }
    }

    Worker(int[] arr) {
        internal = arr;
    }

    public void run() {
        mergeSort(internal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that a multithreaded mergesort is very similar to a regular mergesort, however, when recursively calling the mergesort each half of the list, set up your algorithm to call each merge in a new Thread. You can then wait until both threads are finished, and then merge the two lists together, and return. Simple!

You say in your question that you want to use an `Executor` - I'd suggest that the `java.util.concurrent` package would be of use for this, particularly the `Future` interface.

**Resources:**

- [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort)
- [Java Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html)
- [Concurrent Programming with J2SE 5.0](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/)

Comment: Would it be worth it to note the number of available processors? And only spawn up to that number of threads to avoid scheduling overheads?

Comment: @Cruncher how can one determine if X number of threads will have scheduling overhead ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried just using join method. It basically spawns the threads for each sub problem and waits for the spawned thread to complete using join.

Let me know your comments.

```
   package com.kayan.dsAlgo;

   public class MergeSorter implements Runnable{


private int[] arr;
private int Size;
private int left;
private int right;
private int[] resultArr ;

public MergeSorter(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.Size = arr.length;
    //this.resultArr = new int[j-i+1];
    this.left  = i;
    this.right = j;
}



@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Starting new thread left :"+this.left+" right "+this.right);

    sort();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] ={3,6,4,2,1,10} ;
    MergeSorter mr = new MergeSorter(arr,0,arr.length-1);

    Thread t = new Thread(mr);
    t.start();
    //mr.run();

try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

for (int i :mr.resultArr)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    //int res[]= mr.sort(0,arr.length-1);

}






private void sort() {

    if(left==right && left >=0 )
    {
         this.resultArr = new int[]{arr[left]};
         return;
    }
    if(left>right) return;

    int rightLimit = this.left+(right-left)/2;
    //int leftArr[] = sort( left,rightLimit );

    MergeSorter mleft = new MergeSorter(arr,left,rightLimit);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(mleft);
    t1.start();

     int leftlimit = 1 + rightLimit;            
     //int rightArr[] = sort(leftlimit , right);

     MergeSorter mright= new MergeSorter(arr,leftlimit,right);
     Thread t2 = new Thread(mright);
      t2.start();


       try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      merge(mleft.resultArr,mright.resultArr);



}



private  int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
     resultArr = new int[left.length+right.length];

    int r=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i<left.length && j <right.length )
    {   
        if( i<left.length && j<right.length && left[i] < right[j] )
            resultArr[r++] = left[i++];

        else if( j<right.length && i<left.length && right[j] < left[i])
            resultArr[r++] = right[j++];
    }   


    while(i<left.length)
    {
        resultArr[r++] = left[i++];
    }        

    while(j<right.length)
    {
        resultArr[r++] = right[j++];
    }        


    //System.out.println("resultArr "+resultArr);
    return resultArr;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses the Java7 ForkJoin framework:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03048.html

You can use this framework in Java6 by using the beta version here:
http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/