# what is the equivalent of matlabpool in Scala

Tags: matlab, scala

I am converting some Matlab codes to Scala. In Matlab, there is the **matlabpool** function that is used to define the number of cores to use and "open" the core for parallel computations (and thereafter use for instance **parfor** instead of **for** to run loops in parallel).

```
matlabpool open 4
```

("opens" 4 cores)

```
matlabpool close
```

("closes" the cores for parallel processing)

What is the equivalent of **matlabpool** in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

The Scala compiler generates regular JVM bytecode, so in runtime Scala code has the same capabilities that Java code does. The JVM provides parallelism through light-weight threads (see Thread class and Runnable interface), which will use as many cores as they can (no more than one per thread, off course). See: [Is Multi-Threaded algorithm required to make use of Multi-core processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836937/is-multi-threaded-algorithm-required-to-make-use-of-multi-core-processors)

Twitter's Scala School has a concurrency page (http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html) which indeed shows how to use Java concurrency primitives from Scala.

That said, there are facilities for parallel collections in Scala, which leverage the fork/join Java capabilities from JVM 6 onwards. See: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html