# sorting 50 000 000 numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

Suppose, that we need to sort 50 000 000 numbers. suppose, that the numbers is stored in a file. What is the most efficient algorithm for solving this problem? Parallel algorithm for sorting...

How to do it? Maybe useful link )

## **I can't use standard algorithm**

Therefore i ask you about methods and algorithms :)

Ok.. I read about parallel mergesort... But it's not clear for me.

## **solution, the first version**

[code is located here](http://pastie.org/1330064)

Comment: @Paul He is just from the Matrix - look at his nickname:)

Comment: Why can't you use standard algorithms? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Also, what sort of numbers are these? Integers? bounded? More information would help greatly

Comment: :) to John: something like that ) but more important ) , yes, numbers ) int[] a = new int[50000000]; :)

Comment: A parallel algorithm would be overkill for sorting 50 million numbers on modern processors.  It's a trivial amount of work with standard serial processing, even factoring in file I/O time, i.e., the whole task shouldn't take much more than a minute, most of which is the file I/O.

Comment: My implementation it too lowly... (

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From top of my head, [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) seems to be the best option when it comes to **parallelisation and distribution**, as it uses **divide-and-conquer** approach. For more information, google for "*parallel merge sort*" and "*distributed merge sort*".

For **single-machine, multiple cores** example, see see [Correctly multithreaded quicksort or mergesort algo in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210185/correctly-multithreaded-quicksort-or-mergesort-algo-in-java). If you can use Java 7 fork/join then see: "[Java 7: more concurrency](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/04/java-7-more-concurrency/)" and "[Parallelism with Fork/Join in Java 7](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/fork_join)".

For **distributing it over many machines**, see [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org), it has a distributed merge sort implementation: see [MergeSort](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/MergeSort.html) and [MergeSorter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.19.1-hudson-1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MergeSorter.java). Also of interest: [Hadoop Sorts a Petabyte in 16.25 Hours and a Terabyte in 62 Seconds](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2009/05/hadoop_sorts_a_petabyte_in_162/)

Comment: for sure if you have terabytes of data to sort I'd go for that.

Comment: :) can't find exact algorithm for multi-cores system. Maybe you can give some link or paper?

Answer (score 19):

50 million is not particularly large. I would just read them into memory. Sort them and write them out. It should take just a few seconds.  How fast do you need it be? How compilcated do you need it to be?

On my old labtop it took 28 seconds.  If I had more processors, it might be a little faster but much of the time is spent reading and writing the file (15 seconds) which wouldn't be any faster.

One of the critical factors is the size of your cache.  The comparison itself is very cheap provided the data is in cache.  As the L3 cache is shared, one thread is all you need to make full use of it.

```
public static void main(String...args) throws IOException {
    generateFile();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] nums = readFile("numbers.bin");
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    writeFile("numbers2.bin", nums);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Took "+time+" secs to sort "+nums.length+" numbers.");
}

private static void generateFile() throws IOException {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] ints = new int[50*1000*1000];
    for(int i= 0;i<ints.length;i++)
        ints[i] = rand.nextInt();
    writeFile("numbers.bin", ints);
}

private static int[] readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename), 64*1024));
    int len = dis.readInt();
    int[] ints = new int[len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        ints[i] = dis.readInt();
    return ints;
}

private static void writeFile(String name, int[] numbers) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name), 64*1024));
    dos.writeInt(numbers.length);
    for (int number : numbers)
        dos.writeInt(number);
    dos.close();
}
```

Comment: "As the L3 cache is shared, one thread is all you need to make full use of it." Nevertheless, my C++ code takes 6s (clock and CPU) to sort 50M integers in a single thread, and 3.7s clock / 6.5s CPU to first partition the integers above and below INT_MAX, then sort the lower part in one thread and the upper part in the other. Don't know whether Java would be different, but suggests that the L3 cache is not all there is to it. This is with evenly-distributed values.

Comment: Timing just the sort, it took 13 secs on my laptop with one thread and 7 seconds with two. While that saves 6 seconds (22% of the total) it significantly increased to complexity of the code (not posted ;) Note with 6 cores, I could potential save another 5 seconds but it would still take 18 seconds as the load and save takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Alot really depends on how critical it is to save a few seconds. It took me several minutes to write the code, longer if I actually tested it. ;) In most cases it would NOT be worth the effort IMHO.

Comment: @Peter: I wonder whether the I/O performance can be increased in Java by memory-mapping the file and sorting it in place. It might also simplify the code.

Comment: @Steve, you would need to write a sort routine which sorted an IntBuffer in place. IMHO, memory-mapped files are much faster if you don't need to access all the file e.g. you can skip through it. Note: every get/put to an IntBuffer is a JNI call for direct memory buffer. :|

Comment: Buffers use direct instruction (absolutely inlined) not JNI. A lot of the low level stuff and the entire Unsafe is inlined. One more: arrays sort uses O(n) extra memory for the merge sort.

Comment: @bestsss, You are right about the no JNI, this is something I discovered only recently.  I have seen an overhead in using direct byte buffers but this is not the cause.

Comment: Using DirectBuffer is sort of tricky but also sort of cool, they are basically native C heap stuff (w/ manageable endianness, which is also nice). Reading large files w/ nio Direct buffers (esp on Windows) should yeild extra performance. I can write quite a bit of the impl. details on buffers (down to the real JNI that sends/receives code) and the garbage collection of the non-java-heap area but here it's not the place/time :)

Comment: If you are messing with read/writing data, using Unsafe directly without the protection of a ByteBuffer can be twice as fast.  Also ByteBuffer is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE bytes but Unsafe can allocate much larger sizes. ;)

Answer (score 4):

For sorting than many elements, your best shot is [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). It's usually the algorithms used by databases. Even though is not as fast as [Quick Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), it uses intermediate storage so you don't need huge amounts of memory to perform the sort.

Also, as pointed by sje397 and Scott in the comments, Merge Sort is highly parallelizable.

Comment: And MergeSort is easily parallelized.

Comment: Merge sort is also eminently parallelisable.

Comment: ...and sje397 and I are on exactly the same wavelength. :-)

Comment: @Scott - and also have the same first name ;)

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on the problem domain.  For instance, if all the numbers are positive ints, the best way may be to make an array of 0-MAX_INT and then just count how many times each number occurs as you read the file, and then print out each int with a non-zero count however many times it occurred.  That's an O(n) "sort".  There's an official name for that sort, but I forget what it is.

By the way, I got asked this question in a Google interview.  From the problem constraints I came up with this solution, and it seemed to be the answer they were looking for.  (I turned down the job because I didn't want to move.)

Answer (score 3):

do not be afraid of the large number. in fact, 50 000 000 numbers is not that big. so if the numbers were integers then each number is 4bytes in size so the overall memory needed to be allocated for this array is 50 000 000*4 /1024/1024 = 190.7 Mega Bytes which is relatively small. Having the math done, you can proceed to do QuickSort which runs in O(nLogn). note that the builtin sort method in .net arrays uses QuickSort, im not sure if this is the case in java too.

sorting 250 000 000 integers on my machine took about 2 minutes so go for it :)

Comment: 50 000 000 * 4 ( couse sizeof( item ) == 4 ) == 200 000 000

Comment: Um. You should have multiplied by 4, not divided. 50M values at 4 bytes each takes about 200MB (190MB after binary tax).

Answer (score 2):

They are not so many. If they are 10 bytes long extended for example it would be an array of 500Mbytes, it almost can stay on my phone! ;)
So I'd say go for Quicksort if it's only that.

Answer (score 0):

50e6 numbers is very small nowadays, don't make things more complex than they need to be...

`bash$ sort < file > sorted.file`