# How to implement a multi-threaded MergeSort in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, mergesort, fork-join

Most examples I find of Merge Sort run in a single thread. This defeats some of the advantage of using the Merge Sort algorithm in the first place. Can someone show the proper way to write a Merge Sort algorithm in java using multi-threading.

The solution should use features from the latest version of java as applicable. Many Solutions already on Stackoverflow use plain Threads. I'm looking for a solution demonstrating a ForkJoin with a RecursiveTask, which would seem to be the primary use case the RecursiveTask class was intended for.

Emphasis should be on showing an algorithm with superior performance characteristics including both time and space complexity where possible.

**NOTE**: Neither of the proposed duplicate questions apply since neither provide a solution using Recursive Task which was specifically what this question was asking for.

Comment: Here is an answer using RecursiveAction (if you cannot use Java 8): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210249/14955

Comment: @Thilo Thanks, I wanted a demonstration of RecursiveTask but that link may be helpful to others.

Comment: About this statement in the question: "*This defeats the advantage of using the Merge Sort algorithm in the first place*" This is not the case at all. The "purpose" of merge sort is not to be a multi-threaded algorithm. It is a great sorting algorithm also in a single thread environment.

Comment: @Lii Thanks edited the question to correct for that.

Comment: @mark-rotteveel this is not a duplicate, those links do not satisfy the criteria posted in the question.

Comment: @Thilo Some help removing the duplicate flag maybe? Neither of those links provide a RecursiveTask solution as the question requested.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman You yourself voted to close those other questions as duplicate of your own, so in your opinion they were duplicates of your question. I only reversed the direction of these votes to the older ones. You cannot have your cake and it eat it too...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Don't be so dramatic. As I explained the duplicate flag only made sense in one direction. This question is more specific than the other. You are being absurd.

Comment: I'm not the one here being absurd. If the other questions were duplicates of yours, then so is yours a duplicate of them. If that isn't the case, then you shouldn't have voted to close them as duplicate. I have just taken that self-admitted duplication, and favored the more established questions as target, as that is the common rule when applying duplicate votes. If you now change the argument that your question is "more specific", then you shouldn't have voted to close as duplicate those more general questions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Obviously I'm new here and it was the first time I was using the flag system. My understanding, and perhaps incorrect, is that it is a one-way flag indicating that some question supplies an answer to the current one. If it is not the appropriate flag when one question is simply more specific than the other, so be it, I therefore made the wrong choice. The point of voting is I would have expected others with more expiernce to catch that rather than to be on some high-horse about "teaching a lesson". It all just seems like a very childish response.

Comment: I wouldn't call a 2+ years old account new, but ok. If you want to link between questions, then consider posting a comment to that effect, don't vote to close as duplicate unless you really consider them duplicates. In any case, you might want to consider flagging your answer for moderator attention and have it moved to [Multithreaded quicksort or mergesort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210185/multithreaded-quicksort-or-mergesort) (which already has an answer that uses fork/join + a recursive action).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel for those 2 years my account was mostly idle. But your right a comment may have been better. I figured a process of voting would have figured that out for itself. I dont particularly care enough to bring in a moderator. Just seems very childish on your part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most convenient multi-threading paradigm for a Merge Sort is the fork-join paradigm. This is provided from Java 8 and later. The following code demonstrates a Merge Sort using a fork-join.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MergeSort<N extends Comparable<N>> extends RecursiveTask<List<N>> {
    private List<N> elements;

    public MergeSort(List<N> elements) {
        this.elements = new ArrayList<>(elements);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<N> compute() {
        if(this.elements.size() <= 1)
            return this.elements;
        else {
            final int pivot = this.elements.size() / 2;
            MergeSort<N> leftTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(0, pivot));
            MergeSort<N> rightTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(pivot, this.elements.size()));

            leftTask.fork();
            rightTask.fork();

            List<N> left = leftTask.join();
            List<N> right = rightTask.join();

            return merge(left, right);
        }
    }

    private List<N> merge(List<N> left, List<N> right) {
        List<N> sorted = new ArrayList<>();
        while(!left.isEmpty() || !right.isEmpty()) {
            if(left.isEmpty())
                sorted.add(right.remove(0));
            else if(right.isEmpty())
                sorted.add(left.remove(0));
            else {
                if( left.get(0).compareTo(right.get(0)) < 0 )
                    sorted.add(left.remove(0));
                else
                    sorted.add(right.remove(0));
            }
        }

        return sorted;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        List<Integer> result = forkJoinPool.invoke(new MergeSort<Integer>(Arrays.asList(7,2,9,10,1)));
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

While much less straight forward the following varient of the code eliminates the excessive copying of the ArrayList. The initial unsorted list is only created once, and the calls to sublist do not need to perform any copying themselves. Before we would copy the array list each time the algorithm forked. Also, now, when merging lists instead of creating a new list and copying values in it each time we reuse the left list and insert our values into there. By avoiding the extra copy step we improve performance. We use a LinkedList here because inserts are rather cheap compared to an ArrayList. We also eliminate the call to remove, which can be expensive on an ArrayList as well.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MergeSort<N extends Comparable<N>> extends RecursiveTask<List<N>> {
    private List<N> elements;

    public MergeSort(List<N> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<N> compute() {
        if(this.elements.size() <= 1)
            return new LinkedList<>(this.elements);
        else {
            final int pivot = this.elements.size() / 2;
            MergeSort<N> leftTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(0, pivot));
            MergeSort<N> rightTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(pivot, this.elements.size()));

            leftTask.fork();
            rightTask.fork();

            List<N> left = leftTask.join();
            List<N> right = rightTask.join();

            return merge(left, right);
        }
    }

    private List<N> merge(List<N> left, List<N> right) {
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        while(leftIndex < left.size() || rightIndex < right.size()) {
            if(leftIndex >= left.size())
                left.add(leftIndex++, right.get(rightIndex++));
            else if(rightIndex >= right.size())
                return left;
            else {
                if( left.get(leftIndex).compareTo(right.get(rightIndex)) < 0 )
                    leftIndex++;
                else
                    left.add(leftIndex++, right.get(rightIndex++));
            }
        }

        return left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        List<Integer> result = forkJoinPool.invoke(new MergeSort<Integer>(Arrays.asList(7,2,9,-7,777777,10,1)));
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

We can also improve the code one step further by using iterators instead of calling get directly when performing the merge. The reason for this is that get on a LinkedList by index has poor time performance (linear) so by using an iterator we eliminate slow-down caused by internally iterating the linked list on each get. The call to next on an iterator is constant time as opposed to linear time for the call to get. The following code is modified to use iterators instead.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MergeSort<N extends Comparable<N>> extends RecursiveTask<List<N>> {
    private List<N> elements;

    public MergeSort(List<N> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<N> compute() {
        if(this.elements.size() <= 1)
            return new LinkedList<>(this.elements);
        else {
            final int pivot = this.elements.size() / 2;
            MergeSort<N> leftTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(0, pivot));
            MergeSort<N> rightTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(pivot, this.elements.size()));

            leftTask.fork();
            rightTask.fork();

            List<N> left = leftTask.join();
            List<N> right = rightTask.join();

            return merge(left, right);
        }
    }

    private List<N> merge(List<N> left, List<N> right) {
        ListIterator<N> leftIter = left.listIterator();
        ListIterator<N> rightIter = right.listIterator();
        while(leftIter.hasNext() || rightIter.hasNext()) {
            if(!leftIter.hasNext()) {
                leftIter.add(rightIter.next());
                rightIter.remove();
            }
            else if(!rightIter.hasNext())
                return left;
            else {
                N rightElement = rightIter.next();
                if( leftIter.next().compareTo(rightElement) < 0 )
                    rightIter.previous();
                else {
                    leftIter.previous();
                    leftIter.add(rightElement);
                }
            }
        }

        return left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        List<Integer> result = forkJoinPool.invoke(new MergeSort<Integer>(Arrays.asList(7,2,9,-7,777777,10,1)));
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Finally the most complex versions of the code, this iteration uses an entirely in-place operation. Only the initial ArrayList is created and no additional collections are ever created. As such the logic is particularly difficult to follow (so i saved it for last). But should be as close to an ideal implementation as we can get.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MergeSort<N extends Comparable<N>> extends RecursiveTask<List<N>> {
    private List<N> elements;

    public MergeSort(List<N> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<N> compute() {
        if(this.elements.size() <= 1)
            return this.elements;
        else {
            final int pivot = this.elements.size() / 2;
            MergeSort<N> leftTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(0, pivot));
            MergeSort<N> rightTask = new MergeSort<N>(this.elements.subList(pivot, this.elements.size()));

            leftTask.fork();
            rightTask.fork();

            List<N> left = leftTask.join();
            List<N> right = rightTask.join();

            merge(left, right);
            return this.elements;
        }
    }

    private void merge(List<N> left, List<N> right) {
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        while(leftIndex < left.size() ) {
            if(rightIndex == 0) {
                if( left.get(leftIndex).compareTo(right.get(rightIndex)) > 0 ) {
                    swap(left, leftIndex++, right, rightIndex++);
                } else {
                    leftIndex++;
                }
            } else {
                if(rightIndex >= right.size()) {
                    if(right.get(0).compareTo(left.get(left.size() - 1)) < 0 )
                        merge(left, right);
                    else
                        return;
                }
                else if( right.get(0).compareTo(right.get(rightIndex)) < 0 ) {
                    swap(left, leftIndex++, right, 0);
                } else {
                    swap(left, leftIndex++, right, rightIndex++);
                }
            }
        }

        if(rightIndex < right.size() && rightIndex != 0)
            merge(right.subList(0, rightIndex), right.subList(rightIndex, right.size()));
    }

    private void swap(List<N> left, int leftIndex, List<N> right, int rightIndex) {
        //N leftElement = left.get(leftIndex);
        left.set(leftIndex, right.set(rightIndex, left.get(leftIndex)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        List<Integer> result = forkJoinPool.invoke(new MergeSort<Integer>(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5,9,8,7,6,1,2,3,4))));
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This can probably be rewritten to sort in-place on an internal array instead of allocating new ArrayLists for every `merge` step.

Comment: @Thilo Good point. I will take a stab at that and add it to my answer if i get a good solution.

Comment: @Thilo There ya go I added an copy-in-place version as well. At least, as close as we can get to one as far as i can see.

Comment: I realized my current in-place implementation could be improved by using an iterator instead of get (due to using a linked list). Going to implement that fix and update my answer...

Comment: @Thilo I updated the copy-in-place code from before to use iterators. Now it is even more efficient than before.

Comment: Ok so its not fully in place on the last one. Going to do that as its own post though as it wont be RecursiveTask anymore.

Comment: So last night i realize how to truly make it 100% in-place. Just added one final code snipped demonstrating this. This is different than the first snippet I provided which was just partially in-place. @Thilo